# 502.html doesn't work in django

Tags: django, nginx

When something goes wrong the server returns the default nginx 502 Server Error, I'd like to show my own server error page.

I put 502.html file to the template directory but it doesn't seem to work. It works for 404.html so I am sure I put it to the right directory.

Any ideas how to solve this problem or what could I miss?

Comment: What makes you think Django supports a specific error template for this error? In any case, 502 is Bad Gateway, which usually indicates a problem between nginx and Django, so a template wouldn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 502 means "Bad Gateway", Django (or even the WSGI server in between) is not aware of the request at all. You can add a line similar to the following to your NginX configuration file:

```
error_page 502 /var/www/502.html;
```

Comment: @Inquilabi You should put above line inside your `server` block. That being said, you have a higher chance of getting a proper answer if you post that as a new question.